# How to use torch.compile when freezing model layers during training?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am seeking to fine-tune a foundation model (Wav2Vec) by placing an MLP on top of its final hidden layer. I would like to do this using torch.compile

I would like to do this by freezing the Wav2Vec model for the first few epochs of training (e.g. by setting `requires_grad=False` for all Wav2Vec parameters) and then unfreezing it for the remaining epochs of training. I am also trying to speed up training by using `torch.compile`. However, when I do this, I get the following error when I pass inputs into the model once I unfreeze the model:

RuntimeError: addmm(): functions with out=... arguments don't support automatic differentiation, but one of the arguments requires grad.

My thinking is that the problem here is that, since the first pass through the model is done with `requires_grad=False` for the Wav2Vec parameters, I am creating the computational graph in such a way that it gets confused when I set `requires_grad=True` for the Wav2Vec parameters. Is this correct, and if so, how should I go about handling the problem? I was thinking that I could maybe only compile the model once I am training on the unfreezed model?